# Not able to view contents of first accordion in angular5

Tags: html, css, angular, accordion, primeng

I've created two accordion in my page. The first one contains an ngFor attribute to list the data in it and the second contains static data in it. Whenever I try to open the first accordion, it acquires the necessary space but do not display the data. There is no error in console.

**Note that using only one accordion(the first one) works perfectly fine.**

I want to have both the accordion working with the option of multiple open. Sharing below the code and screenshots for the same.

For the html file :

```
<div class="inner-padding accord1">
    <p-accordion id="accordion1" expandIcon="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down" collapseIcon="fa fa-fw fa-caret-up">
      <p-accordionTab id="accordionTab1" header="ADDITIONAL NOTIFICATIONS" i18n-header> 

        <div *ngFor=" let list of additionalKeys; let i=index">
          <div class="fullwidth notification-parent-row not-hover-effect">
            <div class="fullwidth notification-child-row">
              <div class="width60 notification-child-element">
                <b>{{list.val1}}</b>
              </div>
              <div class="width40 notification-child-element">
                <label class="switch switch custom-switch" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
                  <input [(ngModel)]="list.val2" type="checkbox" [checked]="list.val2">
                  <span></span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </p-accordionTab>
    </p-accordion>
  </div>

<div class="inner-padding accord2">
    <p-accordion id="accordion2" expandIcon="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down" collapseIcon="fa fa-fw fa-caret-up">
      <p-accordionTab id="accordionTab1" header="ADDITIONAL Features" i18n-header> 

         <ng-container>
            <span i18n>Configure the text messages for your app notifications in your preferred language.</span>
         </ng-container>
        <div class="white-box">
          <h6>Notifications Message </h6>
         </div>
      </p-accordionTab>
    </p-accordion>
  </div>
```

There might be some issue with the styling I'm using but is unable to figure as of now. Sharing below the code for .scss file

```
:host /deep/ .ui-accordion{
     margin-bottom: 20px;
}
:host /deep/ .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ddd;
    transition: 0.4s;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(115, 100, 100, 0.2);
    // margin-top: 20px;
}
:host /deep/ .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a{
    padding: 1em;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    display: flex;
&:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1394ff
}
}
```

View with both closed[image]

View with first open [image]

View with second open [image]

View with both open [image]

Comment: what is the error in console? and please share your ts file code also

Comment: There is no error in the console as I mentioned above. There is nothing much in the ts file, just the additional keys list with two properties val1 and val2